# SubSonic LINQ query is 3 times slower than SubSonic.Query.Select

Tags: c#, linq, subsonic, subsonic3

The module I develop makes lots of small selects, inserts, and updates. Modifications made by commands in `SubSonic.Query` namespace ([ActiveRecord is not my weapon of choice](https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues/issue/249)) appear to be much faster than object-by-id select queries written in `LINQ`.

It takes 7.15s to execute the following `LINQ` query 1000 times

```
long a = (
    from u in UserCollection
    where u.UserId == value
    select u.UserId
).FirstOrDefault<long>();
```

While only 2.38s for the thousand runs of `Select` query

```
long a = new SubSonic.Query.Select(provider, "UserId").From<User>()
    .Where<User>(x => x.UserId == value).ExecuteScalar<long>();
```

I took a time to look under the hood of LINQ in SubSonic. The profiler tells that much of processor time of `DbQueryProvider.Execute` calls is spent in `DbQueryProvider.GetExecutionPlan` method - 64 %. 22 % is spent in `System.Linq.Expressions.Complie`, when `DbQueryProvider.Execute` uses only 6 % of time.

I'm totally satisfied of how SubSonic LINQ queries are parsed and compiled. However it would be great to have Compilation facility for repeting SubSonic LINQ queries just like `System.Data.Linq.CompiledQuery` in `Linq2Sql`.

Comment: Is it really an issue at all ? It doesn't seems too slow for real purpose.

Comment: Do you mean a web application by real purpose?
This is an issue for me. Just imagine for how long it would take to make 400k transactions of small selects and inserts. I have to select primary key since SubSonic3 does not allow insert+select.

Answer (score 0):

We did some profiling on this too and found SubSonic's record.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.id=someval) to be up to 20x slower than the same query done through CodingHorror. Logged it here: https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues/258.

The profiler pointed at this in ExecutionBuilder.cs:

```
// this sucks, but since we don't track true SQL types through the query, and ADO throws exception if you
// call the wrong accessor, the best we can do is call GetValue and Convert.ChangeType
Expression value = Expression.Convert(
    Expression.Call(typeof (Convert), "ChangeType", null,
                    Expression.Call(reader, "GetValue", null, Expression.Constant(iOrdinal)),
                    Expression.Constant(TypeHelper.GetNonNullableType(column.Type), typeof(Type))
        ),
    column.Type
    );
```

Disappointing because I really like SubSonic/Linq.

In the end we gave up and I wrote this - http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco.  After porting, our load test showed requests per second went up and CPU load dropped from about 80% to 5%.